# Disable bluetooth calling on Android Wear

Tags: bluetooth, android-wear

I have a Huawei Watch 2 Sport and a Pixel XL connected together, and I have enabled Bluetooth audio on the watch. This was purely for the novelty value of the Dick Tracy style having a phone conversation via the watch.

However, the side affect of this is that the watch now seems to have grabbed Bluetooth audio.

**Symptoms**

- When turning on a previously paired Bluetooth headset it would auto connect; now it must be manually connected
- When turning on a previously paired Bluetooth car kit it would auto connect; now it must be manually connected
- When making a call with a Bluetooth headset connected the audio would be via the headphones; now it appears that the watch is interfering with that

So while the ability to use the watch to make and receive calls is useful, it is very niche compared to the daily problems it creates.

So how can I either resolve the problems above, or disable that the watch handles calls? I would prefer a solution that doesn't involve factory resetting the watch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you can specify in bluetooth settings for each audio device whether it handles Call Audio and/or Media Audio. So turn Media Audio Off for your watch and On for your headset.